# Scheme::R5RS. Trying to make the absolute value procedure

Tags: scheme, r5rs

I'm trying to make the absolute value procedure and code got an error. I don't know why :/

```
(define (abs x)
   (cond ((> x 0) x)
       ((= x 0) 0)
       ((< x 0) (- x))))
```

Error message:

```
define-values: assignment disallowed;
 cannot change constant
  constant: abs
```

Comment: The `abs` function is already there in the library. Rename your `abs` to something else. Racket won't allow you to mutate it with `set!` too.

Comment: also, 0 should not be treated as a separate case

Comment: Is this [Racket R5RS](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/index.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `abs` procedure is already part of the language you're using and you can't create another procedure with the same name. Simply rename it (and the implementation can be simplified a bit, by the way):

```
(define (myabs x)
  (cond ((>= x 0) x)
        (else (- x))))
```

Comment: Thanks! +Why do we have to put brackets around -x (line3)? I've tried without, and it's not showing correct result.

Comment: @Jayjay We need the brackets because we're calling the `-` procedure with a single argument: `x`. If you wrote `-x` it wouldn't work, Scheme thinks `-x` is a variable name which doesn't exist, because a dash can be part of a variable name

Comment: @Jayjay And to add to that `-` and `abs` are variables too and they evaluate to procedure values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution to your question.

```
(define (abs x)
(if (< x 0) (* x -1) (* x 1)))
```

Here is the results in DrRacket:

```
> (abs -4)
4

> (abs 3)
3
```